# Retrieving and using last inserted row ID in sqlite

Tags: c++, sqlite, rowid

I am aware how to retrieve the last inserted row id in sqlite (by `LAST_INSERT_ROWID()`).

Assume there is a business logic class `Customer` with a `string name` and an `int id` field.

Consider this piece of pseudo code/MWE:

```
Customer newCust = Customer();
newCust.setName("Mr. Happy");
createNewCustomer(newCust);
print(newCust.id); // would print "3"

void createNewCustomer(Customer& cust) {
    insertNewCustomer(cust.name); // [pseudo code] inserts a new row in DB; id automatically assigned
    int id = sqlite3::LAST_INSERT_ROWID(); // [pseudo code] retrieve last inserted row id
    cust.id = id;
    return;
}
```

The `Customer` object is passed by reference, so that its `id` field can be updated after the query and used in the rest of the program.

Should I wrap the two steps (inserting and retrieving the last id) in a transaction in order to guarantee the last retrieved id is really the one from the query before (think about a scenario with multiple connections accessing in WAL mode for instance).

Is this even a sophisticated approach?

Comment: The last_insert_rowid goes with the SQLite3 database connection, so unless other threads in the same process use that database connection you're fine.

Comment: @Botje Ah, so two different processes, each with their own database connection, won't cause any problems?

Comment: Correct. Each will have its own last_insert_rowid

Comment: Thank you. Would you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html btw